# Repartition to avoid large number of small files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Currently I have a ETL job that reads few tables, performs certain transformations and writes them back to the daily table.

I use the following query in spark sql 
     **"INSERT INTO dbname.tablename PARTITION(year_month)
            SELECT * from Spark_temp_table "**
The target table in which all these records are being inserted is partitioned at a year X month level. Records which are generated on a daily basis are not that much hence I am partitioning on year X month level.

However, when I check the partition, it has small ~50MB files for each day my code runs (code has to run daily) and eventually I will end up having around 30 files in my partition totalling ~1500MB

I want to know if there is way for me to just create one (or maybe 2-3 files as per  block size restrictions) in one partition while I append my records on a daily basis

The way I think I can do it is to just read everything from the concerned partition   in my spark dataframe, append it with the latest record and repartition it before writing back. How do I ensure I only read data from the concerned partition and only that partition is over written with lesser number of files?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause to control how the records will be distributed in files inside each partition.

to have a single file per partition, you can use `DISTRIBUTE BY year, month`

and to have 3 file per partition, you can use `DISTRIBUTE BY year, month, day % 3`

the full query:

```
INSERT INTO dbname.tablename 
PARTITION(year_month) 
SELECT * from Spark_temp_table
DISTRIBUTE BY year, month, day % 3
```

Comment: Thanks lev for this answer. I also went through number of blogs discussing the same problem and I have come to understand that large number of files per partition can occur because of two broad reasons, 1: When large number of reducers (by default ~200) are writing data to your partition and 2: When you are inserting into your partition on a daily basis (when let us say your partition is on a monthly basis). I believe what you have mentioned will solve Problem 1, but how should I avoid Problem 2?

Comment: also, what you just said can also be fixed by these commands right ? (Again they would fix the issue of large files in a partition which are smaller than allocated block size) **set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true**, **set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000**,  **set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000**